# Calling Third Party Library in Python / Kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

Right now I am trying to making a Port Scanner ... I have installed nmap library from [here](http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/) for python and then i try to make a simple app by import nmap library in my main.py it is crashing and says that can not import nmap but when i run that app in pygame it works but in android phone it's not working

This is the error i am facing

```html
I/python  (14260): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
I/python  (14260): [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
I/python  (14260): [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
I/python  (14260): [INFO              ] [Support     ] Android install hooks
I/python  (14260): [INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
I/python  (14260): [INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
I/python  (14260):  Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  (14260):    File "/home/cyborg/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 30, in <module>
I/python  (14260):  ImportError: No module named nmap
I/python  (14260): Python for android ended.
```

Comment: I don't have a solution, but check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463910/how-do-i-add-a-module-to-kivy-for-android I think it might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Along with jjinking's link in the comments that's here for python-for-android [How do I add a module to Kivy For Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463910/how-do-i-add-a-module-to-kivy-for-android) `./distribute.sh -m "kivy nmap"` and If you are using buildozer to make an apk, then you might want to include nmap in requirements here: `requirements = kivy,...,nmap` in buildozer.spec file.

Comment: I cannot understand what i have to do ???.....do i only have to do is in buildozer.spec file i have to add nmap in requirements ...if yes it gave me error .... else i don't know exactly what you are saying

Comment: That's what I meant, please edit question with your new error.

Comment: also have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880465/buildozer-manually-include-an-external-api/30888353#30888353

Comment: it gave me this error root@kali:~/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android# ./distribute.sh -m "kivy nmap"
Check build dependencies for Kali
Avoid check build dependencies, unknow platform Kali
Check environment
No ANDROIDSDK environment set, abort